# Automatically Add Class To Subchild & Parent LI With jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been searching for hours for a solution to my problem and none of them seem to work the way I would like. I need jQuery to automatically add the class "active" to the main li and also the child li if you are currently on that page.

First code block is the simple structure, second code block is how it needs to look if I were on the "billing_forecast.php" page.

```js
<aside id="sidebar">
<!--| MAIN MENU |-->
        <ul id="side-menu" class="side-menu">
            <li>
                <a href="index.php">
                    <i class="zmdi zmdi-home"></i>
                    <span>Home</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="sm-sub sms-bottom">
                <a href="">
                    <i class="zmdi zmdi-money zmdi-hc-fw"></i>
                    <span>Billing</span>
                </a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="billing_stats.php">Statistics</a></li> 
                    <li><a href="billing_forecast.php">Revenue Estimator</a></li>                                                              
                </ul>
            </li>                                                                        
        </ul>
</aside>
```

```js
<aside id="sidebar">
<!--| MAIN MENU |-->
        <ul id="side-menu" class="side-menu">
            <li>
                <a href="index.php">
                    <i class="zmdi zmdi-home"></i>
                    <span>Home</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="active sm-sub sms-bottom">
                <a href="">
                    <i class="zmdi zmdi-money zmdi-hc-fw"></i>
                    <span>Billing</span>
                </a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="billing_stats.php">Statistics</a></li> 
                    <li class="active"><a href="billing_forecast.php">Revenue Estimator</a></li>                                                              
                </ul>
            </li>                                                                        
        </ul>
</aside>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example I came up with:

```
<ul id="side-menu" class="side-menu">
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/test/">Link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    var path_name = window.location.pathname;

    if( $('.side-menu a[href="'+path_name+'"]').length ){
        $('.side-menu a[href="'+path_name+'"]').parent('li').addClass('active');
        $('.side-menu a[href="'+path_name+'"]').parent('li').parent('ul').parent('li').addClass('active')
    }

});
</script>
```

Comment: THANK YOU!!! I did have to modify the path_name to  var path_name = location.pathname.substr(location.pathname.lastIndexOf("/")+1); to get the filename instead of the directory name with it, but it works! Thanks, I struggled with this for a while